# How exactly _fsopen() works?

Tags: c, msvcrt, crt

How exactly `_fsopen()` works? Does Linux also has similar way of opening files which prepares the file for subsequent shared reading or writing based on `shflag`?

Referred article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fsopen-wfsopen?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Nothing dramatic, it maps directly to CreateFile's dwShareMode argument.  Consider the "x" mode argument in fopen(), available since C11, better than nothing.

Comment: @HansPassant `"x"` is for [`O_EXCL`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) which only helps with file creation.

Comment: Note there is a system call named [`fsopen` in Linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/fsopen.c#L115) (where fs = filesystem), but nothing same to `_fsopen` for sure :)

Answer (score 7):

> How exactly _fsopen() works?

You've linked to the docs.  It does what they say it does.  If you're asking how it is implemented then we cannot answer because that information is proprietary.

> and Does linux also has similar way of opening files which prepares the file for subsequent shared reading or writing based on shflg?

Linux does not have share modes.  That's a Windows quirk.  Under Linux or other Unix-like operating systems such as macOS, you don't need special flags or modes to share files between processes.

Overall, `_fsopen()` is an MS-specific variant of the C standard library's `fopen()` function.  In addition to the share-mode flag, which is not relevant to other operating systems, it performs parameter validation in the manner of various other MS extension functions.  On Linux, one takes responsibility for validating one's own arguments and simply uses `fopen()`.

Comment: Share modes aren't needed to share files between processes but to control Windows' mandatory locking. Linux has limited support for mandatory locking, too.

Comment: @nwellnhof, "sharing" is the term that many Microsoft docs use, including the doc referenced by the question.  Yes, it is implemented with mandatory locking, and yes, it is possible to perform mandatory locking on Linux (with considerable caveats), but that has so different of an interface and is so much less pervasive that I am entirely comfortable with my remarks as given.

Comment: The implementation is not the proprietary secret. Whether the code is exactly licensed in a proprietary way or not, Microsoft now [distributes the ucrt source together with Windows SDK binaries](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20990332). The source code is in `ucrt/stdio/fopen.cpp`, like [this](https://github.com/huangqinjin/ucrt/blob/master/stdio/fopen.cpp#L22).

Answer (score 2):

On Windows files are opened using the [`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) function which uses the [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile) system call.

Argument `dwShareMode` is used to specify file sharing policy and contains combination of flags `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`, `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` which are mapped to `shflag` argument of `_fsopen`.

If you want to know how possible implementation of the function can look like, then first you should keep in mind that MSVCRT tries to support to some equivalent of POSIX file descriptor API. Then check the following functions:

- [`_open_osfhandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle?view=vs-2019) allows you to convert NT `HANDLE` to POSIX-like file descriptor
- [`_fdopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fdopen-wfdopen?view=vs-2019) allows you to get a `FILE *` from a file descriptor (equivalent of POSIX [`fdopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) function).

So the possible implementation can look like this (in pseudo code):

```
FILE *_fsopen(...)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(...);
    int fd = _open_osfhandle(hFile, ...);
    return _fdopen(fd, ...);
}
```

Linux doesn't provide an equivalent of file sharing policy, so there is no equivalent.

PS: Another related function is [`_wsopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sopen-wsopen?view=vs-2019) - combines `CreateFileW` and `_open_osfhandle`.

Comment: The implementation ways vary. Both `_open_osfhandle` and `_fdopen` are not native Win32 APIs; they are likely naturally implemented in terms of some Win32 APIs or internal CRT functions in parallel to `_fsopen`/`_wfsopen` in CRT. At least the actual implementation in `ucrt/stdio/fopen.cpp` does not depend on `_fdopen` this way.

Comment: In https://blog.httrack.com/blog/2013/10/05/creating-deletable-and-movable-files-on-windows I found a reimplementation of `fopen` with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` (exactly what I was looking for), and that is similar to your pseudo-code.